# Finding a counterexample for two conditions about graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following algorithms for DAGs:

1. Minimum path cover counter, which returns the least number of paths which cover the vertices.
2. The following algorithm: count the vertices with in degree = zero, count the vertices with out degree = zero, and return the maximal number of the two.

I know that the two are different, but I'm not able to find a counterexample. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your graph $G$consists of two disjoint subgraphs, $A$ and $B$.

$A$ has $m$ vertices with zero in degree, and $n$ vertices with zero out-degree, with $m>n$.

$B$ has $p$ vertices with zero in degree, and $q$ vertices with zero out-degree, with $p<q$.  And let's say all of $m,n,p,q$ are positive.

To cover $G$ you would need at least $m+q$ paths.

Now $m+q > m+p$ so the minimal path cover counter is not equal to the number vertices with zero in-degree.  And  $m+q > n+q$ so the minimal path cover counter is not equal to the number vertices with zero out-degree.

Comment: Thanks! Another counterexample that I found: a "diamond" graph, A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D.